# Control multiple range sliders Django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

**What I want:**
Multiple Range sliders (the number changes based on user selections) on one page, moving the sliders should update the value and display this in a span element as well as update the model.

**The problem:**
Unfortunately I don't know how to change the values of sliders when there are multiple sliders that are created with a forloop. The span element does not get update and the value element of the slider also does not change when I move the slider handle of a slider.

**Html:**

```
<form method="post">
formset1.management_form }}
for form in formset1 %}
    <div class="custom-slider-container">
        <label>{{ form.name.value }}</label>
        <span id="demo-{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class="range-val">0</span>
        {{ form.weight }}
    <div>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

**Views.py:**

```
initial = Driver.objects.filter(simulation=chosenSim, type='KEY_OUTPUT')
formset = sliders_formset(request.POST or None, queryset=initial)
    if 'sliders_confirm' in request.POST:
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for form in instances:
                form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

**Forms.py**

```
sliders_formset = modelformset_factory(Driver, fields=['name', 'weight'], extra=0,
                                   widgets={'weight': RangeInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-slider', 'max': 20})})
```

If any other information is needed, please let me know and I'll add it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "each" solved my problem!

```
<script>
    var rangeSlider = function(){
        var slider = $('.custom-slider-container'),
        range = $('.custom-slider'),
        value = $('.range-val-label');

        range.each(function(){
            var range_val = $(this).attr('value');
            var range_val = Math.trunc(range_val);
            $(this).prev().html(range_val);
        });

        slider.each(function(){

            value.each(function(){
                var value = $(this).next().attr('value');
                $(this).html(value);
            });

            range.on('input', function(){
                $(this).prev(value).html(this.value);
            });
        });
    };
rangeSlider();
</script>
```